# Unable to 'Apply' Settings to nVidia X Server Settings

Tags: nvidia, xinerama

Im unable to save any settings to nVidia Server Settings. I did 'Save to X Configuration File' but no effect. *Enable Xinerama* is still unchecked the next time I start X.
[image]. Original Image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCxdx.png).

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using `nvidia-settings` for configuration. Run the tool as admin user  like `gksudo nvidia-settings`.

Comment: Tried that - didn't work. Im looking forward to hardcoding the settings in the config file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.